# Synchronize java source from jar file

Tags: java, jar, reverse-engineering

Accidentally i formatted disk with good java source, so now i have old java source and compiled jar file, can i somehow synchronize thems together?

1. I need get java source from jar file
2. How to synchronize with existing project in eclipse

Comment: Only option is to decompile the classes in the jar and create a new project from those generated java files.

Comment: There are tools that you could actually use for that.
For example Java Decompiler GUI: http://jd.benow.ca/

Answer (score 0):

If you have packaged sources in your jar, you can extract them with any file extractor (like [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)) from the src folder inside the jar file.

Otherwise you can use a Java Decompiler, [this one](http://jd.benow.ca/) has a GUI version too.
The second method will not recover your comments/javadoc comments.

Another method would be to use a disk recovery software, but that will only work if you didn't "securely erase" the files on your partition, as the files are still in the disk, just not indexed, and the recovery rate of this method is very low. You can check [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and [photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) for this.